# my splash screen dosn't work xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I want to add a splash screen (I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8ce7OyAgYU&feature=share&fbclid=IwAR0OAz-YUEjnppifXQ4cS85pZPmbxddnuY-Y9gjQw6u5ObRMmUtanDX_h10 )but it dosn't work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NotesDesFrais
{
public class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    Image splashImage;

    public SplashPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        var sub = new AbsoluteLayout();
        splashImage = new Image
        {
            Source = "interrogation.jpg",
            WidthRequest = 100,
            HeightRequest = 100
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(splashImage,
           AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(splashImage,
         new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

        sub.Children.Add(splashImage);

        this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#429de3");
        this.Content = sub;
    }


    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await splashImage.ScaleTo(1, 2000); //Time-consuming processes such as initialization
        await splashImage.ScaleTo(0.9, 1500, Easing.Linear);
        await splashImage.ScaleTo(150, 1200, Easing.Linear);
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());    //After loading  MainPage it gets Navigated to our new Page
    }
}
```

}

the App.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XF.Material.Forms.Material.Init(this);

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SplashPage());
      }
```

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work"? What *do* you see happening? Or are you getting errors?

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing doesn't work means,  there's nothing happen !

Comment: @bhavyajoshi, there's no error,  but it doesn't work

Comment: "nothing happens" = "the app doesn't start", or "I see the first 'real page' with no hint of splash screen", or "I see an empty page where I expected the splash screen"? If "empty", try adding a simple text label (and/or an obvious background color), just to see if it is the page, or just the image that is the issue

Comment: It works fine  in my project . So you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: @HansKeﬆing when i use the breakpoint , everything is okey , but nothing is displayed
i didn't understand where is the problem :/

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i update my publication, and normally all that is important for the progress of this action, I put it here .

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue on my side . So if you can provide a sample which contains the strange behavior I will test it on my side .

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the resource interrogation.jpg in your Andriod (Resources > Drawable) and iOS assets (xAssets)?

Did you also call your SplashPage from App.cs? as follows:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SplashPage());
```

What you are trying to accomplish is a contentpage before the main app starts. It might serve your purpose but please note that this is not a true splashscreen. The splash screen should be shown as soon as possible when the application is launched, but Xamarin.Forms is not initialized until late in the startup sequence, which means that the splash screen must be implemented outside of Xamarin.Forms on each platform.

[For Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen)

[For Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos)

Comment: all what you said , i did it but nothing happens ! :/

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a sample project?